# What is the difference in ZSH between backward-kill-word and backward-delete-word?

Tags: zsh

Both seem to function similarly and [the documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets) states that the difference is that

- one 'deletes' the word and
- the other 'kills' the word.

What is the difference?

Comment: Yes, that sounds funny. I'm just speculating, but reading the section "killring (array)" in the doc you linked, I assume that _kill_ puts the word into a buffer for later use; when using _delete_ it's gone forever.

Comment: Look up 'kill ring', 'kill & yank' The kill ring is like a copy/paste buffer.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly 'kill' and 'yank' are similar to 'cut' and 'paste', but you can kill multiple words one after the other and then yank them back in order from last killed to first killed?

Answer (score 2):

"Kill" and "yank" are the Emacs equivalents of the more modern "cut" and "paste" commands. Any time you've used any widget that has the word "kill" in it to cut some text, you can then use [yank](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-yank) widget (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> in Zsh's default `emacs` keymap) to paste the last killed text. Immediately after doing `yank`, you can then use the [yank-pop](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-yank_002dpop) widget (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> by default) to cycle through the kill ring, which is the list of recent kills. The default size of the kill ring in Zsh is 8, but [that can be modified](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-killring).

But note that, although deleted text doesn't go into the kill ring, it's not immediately lost either: You can usually still get it back by pressing [undo](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-undo) (usually <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>, depending on your OS and terminal app), as long you have not submitted the line yet. But once you've pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> to execute the line, then that won't work anymore.

Comment: I presume that means ‘deleted’ words are forever gone, and don’t go into the kill ring?

Comment: You're correct that deleted words don't go into the kill ring, **but** they're not gone for ever right away: You can still press [undo](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-undo) to get them back.  Usually, pressing ctrl + hyphen (`-`) activates undo, but that seems to vary a bit between terminals and OSs. I've heard that some people need to press ctrl + slash (`/`).

Comment: @Lennart Does this answer your question?